# Entity Framework Many to many saving create existing entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity

I have two classes with a Many-to-Many relationship. When I save my context, Entity Framework is not using the existing Ids, it creates new entry in my database.

My classes are the following : Country and CountryGroup (in my database EF creates as expected CountryGroupCountries).

```
public class Country : EntityBase
{
    public Country()
    {
        CountryGroups = new List<CountryGroup>();
    }


    public virtual List<CountryGroup> CountryGroups { get; set; }
}

public class CountryGroup : EntityBase
{
    public CountryGroup()
    {
        Countries = new List<Country>();
    }

    public virtual  List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public EntityBase()
    {
        DateCreate = DateTime.Now;
        DateUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        DateDelete = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use ASP MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5. When I want to save a CountryGroup, I use Countries that are already in my website. The Ids are the right one.

```
    public virtual void Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        EntityRepository.Insert(entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I just want EF to save my object and the relation to the countries but not. What solution do I have here ? I Feel like I have a misunderstanding of the way EF manages Many To Many.

Answer (score 0):

After many research I believe that my problem lies on the model binder. It must be only creating object without getting them from the context. I overridded my Save Method to replace each Countries in the CountryGroup entity with a fresh one from the context. It is not optimal but I'm going to studie the model binding and then I will arbitrate between those solutions.